# A meta PCG question (challenge?)

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Are there PCG challenges where "general purpose" or "commonly used" [*] programming languages do better than the special PCG targetted languages?

Is this in itself an interesting meta challenge?  I certainly find it so, though I haven't been able to come up with a concrete idea yet!

[*] Let's say: languages on [this list](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html)

Comment: Lots of golfing languages can't do anything that isn't often included in golf challenges. This often includes things such as image processing (but not always), file handling and web requests (again not always), GUI's and stuff with the mouse. I think challenges based around ideas such as these will be more popular than those with "no golfing languages". Though when enough of these questions are asked, the golflangs will include builtins for such tasks

Comment: Not an answer since i don't have time to find specific example, but most of the graphical output tagged challenge are nearly undoable in most golfing language and such score worse than more traditional language.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about code-golf challenges? Otherwise it's easy to find examples where golfing languages are not competitive, like fastest-code and king-of-the-hill.